# Openlayers get coordinates from polygon

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, vector, polygon, html

please could someone help me and bless me with an example of how to get coordinates from a polygon in OpenLayers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Openlayers get coordinates of a circle vector after draw](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19894/openlayers-get-coordinates-of-a-circle-vector-after-draw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get the coordinates of your shape as below code:

```
vectorLayer.features[i].geometry.getBounds();
```

and also you can get covered area, centroid of your shape, vertices of ypur shape, length or geodesic area.

if you want specific feature bounds, you can write order of your feature [i] place like  this:

```
vectorLayer.features[3].geometry.getBounds();
```

and below code will give all bounds of your features
example :

```
var ft = vectorLayer.features;
for(var i=0; i< ft.length; i++){
    console.log(vectorLayer.features[i].geometry.getBounds());
};
```

I hope that will be useful for you....

Comment: Please could you maybe give me an example of this as I am stuck.

Comment: @CaptDragon Question asked. lol.

Comment: @BlakeLoizides  Aragon has it right. This is how you get coordinates from a polygon. In your comment on [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19894/openlayers-get-coordinates-of-a-circle-vector-after-draw) thought it seems like you're having trouble with deleting a polygon now? if so it's a separate question which would merit a new question entry.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to retrieve vertices:

`PolygonLayer.features[0].geometry.getVertices();`

`GetVertices()` returns `Polygon` points coordinates

Comment: Can you improve (edit) your answer with further details? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`XXX.geometry.getVertices();`

`getVertices()` returns the polygon POINT coordinates..