# Get coordinates from a drawing point using OpenLayers 2

Tags: openlayers-2, map-drawing

I implemented a drawing feature (OpenLayers2) on an OpenStreetMap.

I searched about how to get coordinates from a drawing point. But I'm still stuck at this point.

I tried this code in order to get the coordinates instantly after drawing a new point but with no success:

```
 // HOW TO ADD A DRAWING FEATURE
 var DrawMyPoint = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature( MyPointLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Point)//,
     //{feature:GetPointCoordinates});
     // Point for creating point, polygon creating polygon, and so on.

     map.addControl(DrawMyPoint);

 // EVENT LINKED
 document.getElementById("DrawCheckBox").checked = PushOnButtonDraw();
 document.getElementById("DrawCheckBox").checked =GetPointCoordinates();           

 // FUNCTION TO GET COORDINATES OF THE POINT
 function GetPointCoordinates(){
    var coordinates = MyPointLayer.geometry.getBounds();
    console.log(coordinates);
    alert(coordinates);
 }
```

Here is a link where I saw the information about getBounds or getCoordinates :
[Openlayers get coordinates from polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19899/openlayers-get-coordinates-from-polygon)

I am not sure if I may link two functions with the same event, or is there another solution about it?

With getting the coordinates of each newest drawing point (which is my initial question), I would center the map to this coordinates too.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: With no answers now is the ideal time to revise your question to ask only about where you are *currently* stuck.

Comment: I found the answer to my problem. Here is the code i used : /  / HOW TO LINK THIS POINT LAYER INTO AN EVENT
             MyPointLayer.events.on({
                featuresadded : GetCoordinatePoint 
             });

    
             function GetCoordinatePoint(event) {
             var Mycoordonate = event.features[0].geometry.getVertices();
             var stringVertices = "";
             for (var x in Mycoordonate) {
             stringVertices += "(" + Mycoordonate[x].x + "," + Mycoordonate[x].y + ")";
             }
            console.log(stringVertices);
}

Comment: @Karro post it as an answer so people can finds it more easily :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem. Here is the code i used :

```
MyPointLayer.events.on({ featuresadded : GetCoordinatePoint }); 
function GetCoordinatePoint(event) { var Mycoordonate = event.features[0].geometry.getVertices(); var stringVertices = "";
```

`for (var x in Mycoordonate) { stringVertices += "(" + Mycoordonate[x].x + "," + Mycoordonate[x].y + ")"; }`

`console.log(stringVertices); }`